# how to dynamically center nav bar in wp

Tags: css

I currently have this site http://rinique.com/. However, when it is viewed in mobile devices like iPhone and iPad, the nav bar and logo is no longer center anymore. Partly, the reason is I had now force it to be "left: 150px;" to make it look like center.

Is there any way to dynamically force it to center? Below is a snippet of the nav bar css.

```
  #header #navigation {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100%; 
    margin-top: .382em;


  }
  #header #navigation ul.nav {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    left: 150px;
```

Comment: `fix width + margin: auto;` that's all you need if it's horizontal centering

Comment: try putting left in % instead of hard coded number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Apply this css**

```
    #header #navigation{
    text-align:center; // add this line 
    overflow:hidden; // add this line
    float: center; // remove this line 

    }
    #header #navigation ul.nav{
    display:inline-block; // add this line
    vertical-align:top;  // add this line
    float:left: // remove this line
    width: 100%; // remove this line
    left: 150px; // remove this line
    }
```

Comment: Thanks !! I had to add width: 100%; to the #header #navigation and it will work nicely

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#header #navigation ul.nav {
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    display: inline-block; /*added*/
}

#header #navigation {
    border: none;
    background: black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center; /*added*/
}
```